# can't flash recovery image to Ubuntu phone

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, aquaris

I have an Aquaris E4.5. Following the latest update, the software went bonkers and would get stuck with the Ubuntu logo on boot and then hang at that point. I am attempting to reflash the device (having done so multiple times previously with success) but I am receiving an error message on doing so:

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery-krillin.img
2016/10/31 15:51:34 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/10/31 15:51:45 Device is |krillin|
2016/10/31 15:51:45 Flashing version 35 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
can't flash recovery image
```

I have no idea how to proceed. The phone is apparently successfully booting to fastboot but then there is this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if nothing helps, try the android flash tool. It will complete reset the phone (beside you unselect the userdata.img for keeping apps, settings and userdata).

http://www.mibqyyo.com/descargas/2016/09/21/firmware-ubuntu-15-04-ota-13/

http://www.mibqyyo.com/descargas/2015/05/22/herramienta-flash-tool-ubuntu/

Attention: First click download and THEN just connect the device via USB.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. It worked great. I tried the simple download first without success, but then I set it to format first followed by the download, which worked. Thanks! It's good to know of this alternative approach.